# Oracle SQL combine 2 queries from same table with output in 2 different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle SQL database.
I'm trying to combine this 2 queries into one from same table:

```
select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Berlin' or City = 'London')
from Customers;

select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Mannheim' or City = 'Strasbourg')
from Customers;
```

And my output would like to be something like exported on 2 columns:

```
| Berlin & London | Mannheim & Strasbourg |
|-----------------------------------------|
|        5        |         10            |
```

example of db here, https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

I think the answer will be:

```
(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Berlin' or City = 'London'))
union
(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Marseille' or City = 'Tsawassen'));
union
(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Strasbourg' or City = 'Madrid'));
```

Still testing...

Finally got the job done by using this case.
Thanks to everyone involved !

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN  work_zone = 'AMBGI01' OR
          work_zone = 'AMBGI02' OR
          work_zone = 'AMBGI03' AND
          task_type = 'P' THEN work_zone
  END) "HighBay Putaways",
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN  work_zone = 'AMBGI04' OR
          work_zone = 'AMBGI05' OR
          work_zone = 'AMBGI06' OR
          work_zone = 'AMBGI07' AND
          task_type = 'P' THEN work_zone
  END) "LowBay Putaways",
  COUNT(CASE
    WHEN  from_loc_id = 'THEWALL' AND
          task_type = 'P' THEN from_loc_id
    END) "THE WALL",
    COUNT(CASE
    WHEN  tag_id like '%' AND
          from_loc_id like 'EXPANS%' AND
           task_type = 'P' THEN tag_id
     END) "EXPANSION",
   COUNT(CASE
    WHEN  final_loc_id like '_______' AND
          (status = 'In Progress'        OR
          status = 'Released')          AND
          task_type = 'R' THEN final_loc_id
  END) "Replens"
FROM move_task;
```

Comment: is there any relational key between country and customer table?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the structure of the Country and Customers tables.

Comment: i think the asnwer will be `(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Berlin' or City = 'London'))
union
(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Marseille' or City = 'Tsawassen'));
union
(select count(CustomerID) from Customers
where (City = 'Strasbourg' or City = 'Madrid'));
` but not sure if working 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is the following:

```
select count(CASE WHEN City = 'Berlin' or City = 'London' THEN City END) "Berlin & London"
     , count(CASE WHEN City = 'Mannheim' or City = 'Strasbourg' THEN City END) "Mannheim & Strasbourg"
  from Customers
```

Comment: trying it on the link I provided, I got an error .. try it as well, maybe I am doing something wrong.. ?

Comment: The database in your link doesn't support `Oracle` syntax. Which database type do you use?

Comment: Oracle at work, should try this at work and then come with a feedback ;) will get back asap

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear if you have two tables (`customers`, `country`) or one. If there are two you need to show us structure. w3schools.com says there is no such table like `country` and `customers` does not contain `store` column. Anyway you need conditional `count`, something like here:

```
select count(case when city in ('Berlin', 'London')       
                  then 1 end) as "Berlin & London",
       count(case when city in ('Mannheim', 'Strasbourg') 
                  then 1 end) as "Mannheim & Strasbourg"
  from Customers
  where city in ('Berlin', 'London', 'Mannheim', 'Strasbourg')
```

You could also use `pivot`, but this is simpler, more readable and works in older Oracle versions.

Comment: Customers table only sorry